# How to find vote breakdown for EU Parliament voting a non-binding resolution to support the Commission’s tough stance towards Poland?

Tags: european-union, parliament

According to [this article](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-eu-poland/eu-lawmakers-back-action-against-poland-amid-democracy-concerns-idUSKCN1GD4KL), on 1st of March 2018, there was a vote in EU Parliament related to supporting a non-binding resolution to support the Commission’s tough stance towards Poland.

> The European Parliament voted on Thursday 422 in favour to **147
>   against**, with 48 abstentions, on a non-binding resolution to support
>   the Commission’s tough stance towards Poland.

During an interview (cannot find the transcript, but it is mentioned in [this article](https://www.digi24.ro/stiri/actualitate/politica/dragnea-explica-votul-eurodeputatilor-psd-in-cazul-poloniei-romania-n-are-cum-sa-ajunga-in-aceasta-situatie-889119)), [Ana Gomes](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/28306/ANA_GOMES_home.html) mentioned that Romanian Socialist Democrat party was the only party from Group of the Progressive Alliance of Socialists and Democrats in the European Parliament that voted for Poland (so they were a fraction of those 147).

I have taken a look upon [European Parliament site](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/votes.html?tab=votes), but could not find vote breakdown by party (I probably do not know where to look).

**Question:** How to find vote breakdown for EU Parliament voting a non-binding resolution to support the Commission’s tough stance towards Poland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can find the issues listed [here](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-%2F%2FEP%2F%2FNONSGML%2BPV%2B20180301%2BRES-VOT%2BDOC%2BPDF%2BV0%2F%2FEN&language=EN).  You're interested in topic 12 (page 9).  Specifically, it looks like you can see the vote totals under RCV/EV remarks column, with the resolution as a whole lining up with the numbers you quoted.  Importantly, it also tells us this was resolution B8-0119/2018

If we go to the [roll call results](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-%2F%2FEP%2F%2FNONSGML%2BPV%2B20180301%2BRES-RCV%2BDOC%2BPDF%2BV0%2F%2FEN&language=EN), we see in the table of contents that this resolution, and it's amendments, were votes 24-30 (30 being the final resolution).  The results are on page 65-66.

It may be easier to read the PDF, as its formatting got lost the copy-paste, but...

### The 422 in favor:

ALDE: Ali, Arthuis, Auštrevičius, van Baalen, Bearder, Becerra Basterrechea, Bilbao Barandica, Calvet Chambon, Charanzová,
Cornillet, Deprez, Dlabajová, Giménez Barbat, Harkin, Huitema, Hyusmenova, in 't Veld, Jäätteenmäki, Ježek, Kallas,
Katainen, Klinz, Kyuchyuk, Lalonde, Løkkegaard, Marinho e Pinto, Meissner, Michel, van Miltenburg, Mlinar, Müller,
Nagtegaal, Nart, Pagazaurtundúa Ruiz, Petersen, Radoš, Ries, Riquet, Rochefort, Rohde, Selimovic, Telička, Torvalds,
Tremosa i Balcells, Uspaskich, Vajgl, Vautmans, Väyrynen, Verhofstadt, Wierinck, Wikström

ECR: Demesmaeker, Loones, Lucke, Macovei, Stevens, Van Bossuyt

ENF: Bizzotto, Borghezio

GUE/NGL: Anderson Martina, Benito Ziluaga, Björk, Boylan, Carthy, Chrysogonos, Eck, Ernst, Flanagan, Forenza, González Peñas,
Hadjigeorgiou, Hazekamp, de Jong, Kari, Kouloglou, Kuneva, Kyllönen, Lösing, Maltese, Matias, Michels, Mineur,
Miranda, Papadimoulis, Sakorafa, Sánchez Caldentey, Schirdewan, Scholz, Spinelli, Torres Martínez, Urbán Crespo,
Vergiat, Zimmer

NI: Karlsson, Sonneborn

PPE: Adaktusson, Alliot-Marie, Andrikienė, Arimont, Ashworth, Ayuso, Bach, Balz, Becker, Belet, Bendtsen, Böge, Boni, Brok,
Buda, Cadec, van de Camp, Casa, Caspary, del Castillo Vera, Christoforou, Cicu, Cirio, Clune, Coelho, Corazza Bildt,
Danjean, Dantin, Dati, Delahaye, Deß, Díaz de Mera García Consuegra, Didier, Dorfmann, Ehler, Engel, Estaràs Ferragut,
Ferber, Fernandes, Fisas Ayxelà, Fjellner, Florenz, Gahler, Gambús, Gardini, Gieseke, Girling, González Pons, de
Grandes Pascual, Gräßle, Grossetête, Guoga, Hayes, Herranz García, Hohlmeier, Hökmark, Jazłowiecka, JiménezBecerril
Barrio, Juvin, Kalniete, Karas, Kariņš, Kefalogiannis, Kelam, Kelly, Koch, Kudrycka, Kuhn, Kukan, Kyrtsos,
Lamassoure, de Lange, Langen, Lavrilleux, Lenaers, Lope Fontagné, López-Istúriz White, McAllister, McGuinness,
Maletić, Malinov, Mandl, Mann, Marinescu, Mato, Maydell, Melo, Metsola, Millán Mon, Moisă, Monteiro de Aguiar, MorinChartier,
Mureşan, Niebler, Niedermayer, van Nistelrooij, Peterle, Pieper, Pietikäinen, Pitera, Polčák, Preda, Proust,
Quisthoudt-Rowohl, Radtke, Rangel, Reding, Ribeiro, Rolin, Ruas, Rübig, Saïfi, Salafranca Sánchez-Neyra, Salini,
Sander, Sarvamaa, Schmidt, Schreijer-Pierik, Schulze, Schwab, Šojdrová, Sommer, Štětina, Stolojan, Šuica, Thun und
Hohenstein, Valcárcel Siso, Vălean, Vandenkendelaere, Verheyen, Virkkunen, Voss, Vozemberg-Vrionidi, Weber Manfred,
Wieland, Zammit Dimech, Zeller, Zovko

S&D: Aguilera García, Anderson Lucy, Androulakis, Arena, Assis, Ayala Sender, Balčytis, Bayet, Benifei, Beňová, Berès, Bettini,
Blanco López, Blinkevičiūtė, Bonafè, Brannen, Briano, Bullmann, Cabezón Ruiz, Caputo, Christensen, Corbett, Costa,
Cozzolino, Dalli, Dance, Danti, De Castro, Delvaux, De Monte, Denanot, Detjen, Fernández, Fleckenstein, Freund,
García Pérez, Gardiazabal Rubial, Gebhardt, Geier, Gill Neena, Giuffrida, Gomes, Grammatikakis, Graswander-Hainz,
Griffin, Gualtieri, Guerrero Salom, Guillaume, Guteland, Gutiérrez Prieto, Hedh, Honeyball, Howarth, Ivan, Jaakonsaari,
Jáuregui Atondo, Jongerius, Kadenbach, Kaili, Kammerevert, Kaufmann, Keller Jan, Khan, Kirton-Darling, Kofod, Kohn,
Köster, Krehl, Kumpula-Natri, Kyenge, Kyrkos, Lange, Leinen, Lietz, López Aguilar, Ludvigsson, McAvan, Mamikins,
Maňka, Manscour, Martin David, Martin Edouard, Maurel, Mavrides, Mayer Alex, Melior, Mizzi, Molnár, Moody, Moraes,
Morgano, Nekov, Neuser, Niedermüller, Noichl, Padar, Palmer, Panzeri, Pargneaux, Peillon, Piri, Pirinski, Poc, Poche,
Post, Preuß, Regner, Revault d'Allonnes Bonnefoy, Rodrigues Liliana, Rodríguez-Piñero Fernández, Rodust, Rozière,
Sant, dos Santos, Sârbu, Schaldemose, Schlein, Sehnalová, Serrão Santos, Silva Pereira, Simon Peter, Simon Siôn,
Sippel, Smolková, Stihler, Szanyi, Tang, Tarabella, Thomas, Toia, Ujhelyi, Ulvskog, Valenciano, Van Brempt, Vaughan,
Viotti, Ward, Weidenholzer, von Weizsäcker, Werner, Westphal, Wölken, Zanonato, Zoffoli, Zorrinho

Verts/ALE: Affronte, Albrecht, Andersson, Auken, Bové, Buchner, Bütikofer, Dalunde, Delli, Durand, Eickhout, Engström, Giegold,
Häusling, Hautala, Heubuch, Hudghton, Jadot, Jávor, Joly, Keller Ska, Lambert, Lamberts, Lochbihler, Marcellesi, Reda,
Reimon, Reintke, Rivasi, Sargentini, Scott Cato, Škrlec, Smith, Solé, Šoltes, Staes, Tarand, Taylor, Trüpel, Turmes,
Urtasun, Valero, Waitz, Ždanoka

### The 147 against:

ALDE: Diaconu, Grigule-Pēterse, Mazuronis, Nicolai

ECR: Barekov, Bashir, Campbell Bannerman, Czarnecki, Czesak, van Dalen, Dalton, Dohrmann, Dzhambazki, Fotyga, Fox,
Gosiewska, Halla-aho, Hannan, Hoc, Jurek, Kamall, Karim, Karski, Kłosowski, Kölmel, Krasnodębski, Krupa, Kuźmiuk,
Legutko, McIntyre, Marias, Matthews, Messerschmidt, Ożóg, Piotrowski, Poręba, Procter, Ruohonen-Lerner, Sernagiotto,
Škripek, Starbatty, Sulík, Swinburne, Theocharous, Tomaševski, Tomašić, Tošenovský, Ujazdowski, Vistisen, Wiśniewska,
Zahradil, Zīle, Złotowski

EFDD: Agnew, Aker, Arnott, Batten, Bergeron, Bullock, Carver, Coburn, (The Earl of) Dartmouth, D'Ornano, Etheridge, Finch, 
Hookem, Iwaszkiewicz, Lundgren, Meuthen, Montel, O'Flynn, Parker, Philippot, Reid, Seymour, Winberg

ENF: Arnautu, Atkinson, Bay, Bilde, Boutonnet, Colombier, Elissen, Goddyn, de Graaff, Jalkh, Kappel, Lebreton, Lechevalier,
Loiseau, Martin Dominique, Marusik, Mayer Georg, Mélin, Monot, Obermayr, Rebega, Schaffhauser, Troszczynski,
Vilimsky, Zijlstra, Żółtek

GUE/NGL: Konečná, Maštálka

NI: Chauprade, Dodds, Epitideios, Fountoulis, Gollnisch, Korwin-Mikke, Morvai, Saryusz-Wolski, Synadinos, Voigt

PPE: Bocskor, Deli, Deutsch, Erdős, Hölvényi, Hortefeux, Járóka, Kósa, Liese, Maullu, Mussolini, Petir, Schöpflin, Šulin, Tőkés,
Tolić, Tomc, Ţurcanu, Ungureanu, Winkler Hermann, Winkler Iuliu, Záborská, Zver

S&D: Boştinaru, Frunzulică, Grapini, Kouroumbashev, Nica, Paşcu, Pavel, Popa, Tănăsescu, Țapardel

### The Absentions:

ALDE: Mihaylova

ECR: Gericke

EFDD: Adinolfi, Aiuto, Beghin, Corrao, D'Amato, Evi, Moi, Pedicini, Tamburrano, Valli, Zullo

GUE/NGL: Chountis, Couso Permuy, Ferreira, López Bermejo, Pimenta Lopes, Senra Rodríguez, Sylikiotis, Vallina, Viegas

NI: Balczó, Papadakis Konstantinos, Zarianopoulos

PPE: Ademov, Bogovič, Csáky, Kovatchev, Mikolášik, Morano, Nagy, Novakov, Pabriks, Pospíšil, Saudargas, Sógor, Štefanec,
Urutchev

S&D: Cristea, Geringer de Oedenberg, Gierek, Liberadzki, Łybacka, Papadakis Demetris, Zemke

Verts/ALE: Harms, Ropė

Comment: Thank you. However, I think the way to find this information can be greatly improved.